# How to get the files necessary for a floating action button?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

All across the internet and several Stack Overflow pages, there are detailed instructions for the implementation of Floating Action Buttons, but nobody explains where I might be able to acquire the icon myself. Is everyone creating his own action buttons for his UI, or is there a downloadable library somewhere I have yet to discover? 
Please link and explain!

Comment: There isn't a link. You can build your custom floating action button icon.

Comment: I'm prepared to use Gimp, but that seems like overkill for something so simple. Suggest any other methods of constructing a FAB?

Comment: You can create icons from here
http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: For size and other look at :http://www.google.co.in/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-usage

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't provide any code for it, but it should be pretty basic to build yourself.

If you'd prefer to use a library for it, I use this one by shamanland: [floating-action-button](https://github.com/shamanland/floating-action-button).  You can change the color and icon displayed, and have it auto-hide when the user is scrolling.

There's another popular library by futuresimple here: [android-floating-action-button](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button).  It includes support for sub-actions with text labels, and two button sizes, but won't give you auto-hiding on scrolling. I think I started with this one and switched to shamanland's, but I don't remember why.

Answer (score 0):

I am creating `Floating Action Button` and `shadow` with .xml files as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29233460/3736955) and using icons from [icons8.com](http://icons8.com/web-app/new-icons/all), it has Android Lollipop specific icons.