# Is it possible to use CardView to make shadow for Floating Action Button?

Tags: android, shadow, android-cardview, floating-action-button

I know `CardView` is not made for this, but in theory if `cardCornerRadius = view_size / 2` it should result in circle.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Try using app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false" for your card view. Not sure that it will work as you want or not. @Dmytro Danylyk

Comment: @Pooja as you can see on screenshot, this attribute is already set.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing real, animated shadows is not that difficult and you can try to achieve Lollipop's effect on any Android down to Froyo. Here's how it works:

1. Draw your view to an offscreen bitmap using LightingColorFilter(0,0)
2. Blur that bitmap using ScriptIntrisincBlur. Set the blur radius to your elevation value.
3. Draw that blurred bitmap beneath your floating action button.

For an example implementation see:

- Shadow generator, blurs views: https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/shadow/ShadowGenerator.java
- LinearLayout with shadows support, check drawChild() method: https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/widget/LinearLayout.java#L102

Basically Carbon library tries to mimic Lollipop's effect as good as possible. I'm aware of that importing such library might be an overkill, but if you wish you can copy only the interesting part of code and use it in your app.

Comment: I am using simpler solution `setShadowLayer` https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/shadow-layout/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/dd/ShadowLayout.java#L118
FYI: Instead of `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` use `Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8` it will decrease size of generated `Bitmap` by 3 times.

Comment: setShadowLayer doesn't work well with hardware acceleration, which is not acceptable for me. Thanks for the hint with ALPHA_8 config - I have to check that :)

Comment: `setShadowLayer` doesn't work if you are using it inside view `Canvas`. If you are creating `Canvas` object from `Bitmap` it works https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/shadow-layout/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/dd/ShadowLayout.java#L87

Comment: It works because Canvas backed by a simple Bitmap is not hardware accelerated. It means that shadows aren't hardware accelerated as well. I'm wondering what's the performance of that solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not suggested, it is against pattern. `CardView` is used for list. You can make your own `Floating Action Button` and shadow with `ImageView`.

`activity_layout.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ....
    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/add_courses_button"
            android:layout_width="64dp
            android:layout_height="64dp"

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"

            android:background="@drawable/fab"
            android:tint="@color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/add_image"/>
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

`fab.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <!-- Shadow -->
            <item android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp">
                <layer-list>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#08000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="3px"
                                android:left="3px"
                                android:right="3px"
                                android:top="3px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#09000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="2px"
                                android:left="2px"
                                android:right="2px"
                                android:top="2px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#10000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="2px"
                                android:left="2px"
                                android:right="2px"
                                android:top="2px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#11000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#12000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#13000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#14000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#15000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#16000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                </layer-list>
            </item>

            <!-- Blue button pressed -->
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#0099cc"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_enabled="true">

        <layer-list>
            <!-- Shadow -->
            <item android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp">
                <layer-list>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#08000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="3px"
                                android:left="3px"
                                android:right="3px"
                                android:top="3px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#09000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="2px"
                                android:left="2px"
                                android:right="2px"
                                android:top="2px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#10000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="2px"
                                android:left="2px"
                                android:right="2px"
                                android:top="2px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#11000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#12000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#13000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#14000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#15000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <solid android:color="#16000000"/>
                            <padding
                                android:bottom="1px"
                                android:left="1px"
                                android:right="1px"
                                android:top="1px"
                                />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                </layer-list>
            </item>

            <!-- Blue button -->
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#33b5e5"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>

    </item>

</selector>
```

Result is like this:

[image: android custom floating action button]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but such button is hard to maintain.

Comment: Would this shadow look ok on higher pixel density devices? I haven't tried it yet, but I'm just wondering if it would work if I use dp instead.

Answer (score -1):

Technically seems like possible but practially it doesn't.

If you want to use the button like that, I suggest you to use this library. It works pretty well. https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary